# ISO-8559-1 encoding is storing incorrect data in latin1 DB. A few questions

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding

Now I’m going to say the dreaded ‘E’ word. Encoding. I’m aware that it has been [covered](http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/latin1%20encoded%20tables%20or%20databases%20utf8%20data%20stored%20convert%20them%20native%20mysql%20utf8%20tables) [to](http://www.bluebox.net/about/blog/2009/07/mysql_encoding/) [death](http://nicj.net/mysql-converting-an-incorrect-latin1-column-to-utf8) all over the Internet but there are a couple of things I need clarifying.

Now I have a script whose charset is ISO-8559-1 and its writing to series of latin1_swedish_ci fields. The data within these fields though isn’t accurate, I get symbols like ÃƒÂª and Ã§Ã within my strings. These are obviously "non-standard" characters.

Now when it comes to output, if I serve my HTML in ISO-8859-1 my content doesn’t render correctly but when I use UTF-8 ***most*** of it does.

Now to the questions:

1. I’m assuming the database is storing the data incorrectly to the human eye as it needs to use multiple bytes, is this correct?
2. Why do most symbols render correctly when using UTF-8 charset but not when using ISO?
3. In order to get all characters to save in the database and render correctly I assume I need to use UTF-8 throughout. Moving forward would you take the hit or is it acceptable to keep this kind of data in the DB and convert it each time. We have a lots and lots of non-english characters.

Thanks

Richard

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: It sounds like you stored UTF-8 encoded data in your `latin1` columns.  Probably because you didn't set the connection character set.

Comment: Cheers eggyal, I think that has whats happened. Just to be clear does this overwrite the charset which PHP is using?

Comment: Just use UTF everywhere. Switching between character sets is one of the worst possible things to do.

Comment: use mb_* php library and stick to one encode. Accept any encoding bt do a clean up with desired characters before saving them

Comment: Thanks all, time to bite the bullet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted, I've blogged about the steps taken here: https://support.servertastic.com/converting_latin1_utf8/